# Not been able to receive the sms from the c# application

Tags: c#, sms, windows

I'm working on an Application that sends a text message to a number. I'm using the GSMComm Library for the application.

The program gets the detail from SQL database and there is a specific time when it sends it to the number.

```
bool check;
            do
            {
                detail = new string[3];

                //Gets the Details from the database
                detail = q.GetQueuePhone();

                // the target time of sending the sms
                int time = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDateTime(detail[2]).TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds);

                if (time != 0)
                {
                    //time left
                    int Interval = time - Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds);

                    //Start counting
                    Thread.Sleep(Interval);

                    SmsSubmitPdu pdu;
                    //detail[1] have the Phone Number
                    pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(TextMsg, detail[1]);
                    comm.SendMessage(pdu);

                    //sending on that number is done
                    q.UpdateCustomerStat(detail[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    //recheck the database again
                    check = true;
                    Thread.Sleep(30000);
                }
            } while (check);
```

My problem starts when the message that have been sent by the program is not receive by the phone number.

Can anyone help me?

Edit:
This is the log from GSMComm

```
Info       16:07:48.005 Sending message...
Info       16:07:50.091 Message sent successfully.
Info       16:07:48.015 [gsmphone] Activating PDU mode...
Verbose    16:07:48.016 [gsmphone] << AT+CMGF=0
Verbose    16:07:48.016 [gsmphone]    
Verbose    16:07:48.033 [gsmphone] >> 
Verbose    16:07:48.033 [gsmphone]    OK
Verbose    16:07:48.033 [gsmphone]    
Info       16:07:48.033 [gsmphone] Sending message...
Verbose    16:07:48.034 [gsmphone] << AT+CMGS=28
Verbose    16:07:48.034 [gsmphone]    
Verbose    16:07:48.036 [gsmphone] >> 
Verbose    16:07:48.036 [gsmphone]    > 
Verbose    16:07:48.036 [gsmphone] << 0011000C819051258225 30000A70F54747A0E4ACF416110BD3CA78700
Verbose    16:07:50.091 [gsmphone] >> 
Verbose    16:07:50.091 [gsmphone]    
Verbose    16:07:50.091 [gsmphone]    +CMGS: 27
Verbose    16:07:50.091 [gsmphone]    
Verbose    16:07:50.091 [gsmphone]    OK
Verbose    16:07:50.091 [gsmphone]    
Info       16:07:50.091 [gsmphone] 21 characters received after 2059 ms.
Info       16:07:50.091 [gsmphone] Message reference = 27
```

Comment: Doesn't that sound like the message isn't been sent? Are they any logs you can look at to verify the message was sent?

Comment: There is a log function that the library can provide. I don't understand the log it generates

Comment: Can you clear the log, do a send message, then edit your answer with the log files that it generated while doing the send?

Comment: Ok, just have to ask to get these things out the way. Are you sure you have the right phone number? can you send messages to that phone normally. Have you put it in international format. Sometimes carriers or other things need the full international number. e.g. in Australia I can just type 0400000000 as a mobile number but if I wish to send it over an sms app I need to write it as 61400000000

Comment: Yes, the phone number and the format is right. I even strip down the code. The specific area where the message isn't received anymore is after the thread sleep. I need to have an interval before sending the message

Comment: Just reading into the doco, it says: •Q: How can I, after sending an SMS message, receive a notification that the message has been delivered?
 
A: You can request a status report along with a message. The SmsSubmitPdu class has a property "RequestStatusReport". Set this to true before sending the message, and you will receive a report in the form of a special SMS message any time something important happens to your message. The report includes a code that tells you what is going on.

Can you do this and see what it says.

Comment: @Amel - If you don't understand how the log is generated how can you expect to understand the problem.  I would first get an understanding of the log file and what is logged and the reason for it.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for not understanding the log I only did a commparison on the one that completes the message process and both of them have the same logs like this the only real difference is that mine haven't been received by the number

Comment: @Adam the RequestStatusReport didn't do anything. I even tried it in the original demo source of GSMComm

Comment: The line in your log shows: Info       16:07:50.091 [gsmphone] 21 characters received after 2059 ms. 
 This intrigues me as I want to find out what it is. Just as a side note can you run the demo project and send a message? or try a different GSM phone. Just trying to narrow down what is failing. The code or the phone.